# Get Holders timeout

Tags: getprogramaccounts

I want get total holders of a token, this is my code :

```
const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    programId,
    {
        dataSlice: {
           // for amount data slice
            offset: 64, // number of bytes
            length: 72, // number of bytes
        },
        filters: [
            {
                dataSize: dataSize, // number of bytes
            },
            {
                memcmp: {
                    offset: 0, // number of bytes
                    bytes: tokenAddress.toBase58(), // base58 encoded string
                }
        ],
    }
);
```

And after I filter and get only accounts with amount > 0.

But when the token has many holders, it takes a lot of time and timeout.

is there another way to do it ? or is it related to my  provider_endpoint used in the connection ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your RPC connection that would be restricting this. You could try changing providers but the more sustainable option will be using a provider that indexes this. Birdeye and Solscan have paid plans with this and some RPC providers either have or are working on APIs with this information.